# How to generate unigram, bigram and trigram from a large csv file and count their frequencies using nltk or pure python

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, n-gram

I used this code and its generating unigrams, bigrams,trigrams from the given text. But i want to extract unigram,bigram and trigram from a specific coumn of a large csv file. Kindly help me how should i proceed

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, some fancy code to produce the DataFrame.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

sio = StringIO("""I am just going to type up something because you inserted an image instead ctr+c and ctr+v the code to Stackoverflow.
Actually, it's unclear what you want to do with the ngram counts.
Perhaps, it might be better to use the `nltk.everygrams()` if you want a global count.
And if you're going to build some sort of ngram language model, then it might not be efficient to do it as you have done too.""")

with sio as fin:
    texts = [line for line in fin]

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': texts})
```

Then you can easily use `DataFrame.apply` to extract the ngrams, e.g.

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import partial

from nltk import ngrams, word_tokenize

for i in range(1, 4):
    _ngrams = partial(ngrams, n=i)
    df['{}-grams'.format(i)] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: Counter(_ngrams(word_tokenize(x))))
```

Comment: Note: `DataFrame.apply()` is slow.